# ajax suggestion with table format in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have a simple jsf form with fields  firstname, lastname, and save button.

Now when user will enter his firstname, he should get suggesstions(ajax) from existing records(from database).

And more important thing suggestionbox should be in  table format  as shown in fig, and if user will click on any suggestion.
[image]
How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go for primefaces autocomplete

take a look at the showcase

[AutoComplete - Pojo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf)

just start typing Messi (with capital) in the second autocomplete box

in that example there are two columns....